# Как сделать всем слайдам slick'a одинаковую высоту?

Tags: javascript, slider, flexbox, slick.js

Нужно сделать что бы все слайды были одинаковой высоты, а конкретнее, что бы они выравнивались по высоте со слайдом в котором больше всего контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал задать `display:flex` для родителя сладов, т.к. тогда `flex-элементы` растянулись бы по высоте самого высокого, но дело в том, что `slick` создает дополнительные `div` элементы, из-за этого `flex-элементами` становятся не те элементы которые нужны.

Сниппет: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGdqqN

```js
$('.slide_wrapper').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide_wrapper {
  display: flex !important;
}

.slides {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide_wrapper">
      <div>
        <div class="slides slides_1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slides slides_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slides slides_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slides slides_4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slides slides_5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Рекомендую в качестве альтерниативы slick'у - http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы растянуть слайды, нужно задавать `display:flex` непосредственному родителю слайдов(`.slick-track`).

```js
$('.slide_wrapper').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #cda;
  padding:10px;
}
.slide_wrapper .slick-track{
  display:flex;
}
.slick-slide.slides{
  height:auto;
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide_wrapper">
      <div class="slides slides_1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum
        error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
      </div>
      <div class="slides slides_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit
      </div>
      <div class="slides slides_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! praesentium illum error delectus
        optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?Suscipit nostrum?
      </div>
      <div class="slides slides_4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
      </div>
      <div class="slides slides_5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at, voluptatem similique tempora voluptate quia in ea minima earum consequatur eveniet, praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium
        illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?praesentium illum
        error delectus optio nobis eaque distinctio! Suscipit nostrum?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: В том, то и дело, что пробовал так делать в своей реально верстке, не вышло, может что-то не так сделал. Надо будет попробовать еще раз.